# Implementing ability to capture payments offline from orders

Tags: orders, payment

So we're trying to develop a way of capturing payments offline in Magento as a result of [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/raising-invoice-for-manual-telephone-orders-where-payment-taken-outside-of-mag/6554).

If our client takes telephone/manual orders, they need the ability to capture the payment when Magento can't auto detect that payment has been made. I was hoping to achieve this in the simplest possible way like:-

[image: capture payments offline]

A button that they can simply click on the order page to capture the payment manually and push the order to the next stage of the ordering process so that they can ship the order.

What would be the best approach for this?

In an ideal world, we would make this button trigger the function as detailed in Inchoo's suggestion which can also be seen at [our previous thread on this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/raising-invoice-for-manual-telephone-orders-where-payment-taken-outside-of-mag/6554).

Could anyone advise of a way this can be done effectively to achieve what we're after?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the on account/invoice payment (free) extension from http://mamoc.com/rembours-and-invoice-payment-method. You can configure this extension to create an invoice when the order is completed but with the invoice payment state as pending. This way you only need to capture the payment for the invoice to set the order to the next stage.

Comment: I've got no idea how to use this extension. There are no instructions or documentation. What exactly does it do? I can't see that anything changes in the Magento back office? Please could you point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: If you installed the extension you should have an extra payment method, in the configuration for the payment method you can set the create invoice status as pending. After that every order created with this extension will have an invoice created with that state. When the payment is done, you can capture the invoice setting the order to the processing state.

Comment: Ah, I see the payment methods now. Unsure what the difference between 'Op Rekening' and 'Rembours' is though. There is also no option of 'Pending' in the create invoice status dropdown - it only lists 'Processing'. Thanks.

Comment: The payment method does not appear in the admin 'create order' screen either so we cannot select it to raise telephone orders. It does appear on the frontend though.

Comment: Please could you advise on this? Currently we cannot see how this extension answers our issue if it only appears in the front end.

Comment: Are you able to advise at all as per your extension please?

Comment: It's strange that the payment extension is visible on the frontend but not in the backend, what other options did you configure for the extension?

Comment: I think you misunderstand... The extension appears in 'Payment Methods' in the system configuration but I can't see anywhere to use it when we raise a manual / telephone order in the back office (admin panel). I'm referring to this section of the create order screen as can be seen in [this screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8388505/Guest%20Blogging/screenshots/missing-payment-method.png).